# R --markdown to latex - tables do not show up

Tags: latex, markdown, knitr, xtable, pandoc

I am using Knitr in Rstudio, to generate markdown files. I display the tables via xtable package and it shows up nicely in html file. However, when I converd .md to latex via pandoc - the latex file does not contain the tables as it is supposed to be, but only the values in table without any command.

### Markdown - Knitr input

In order to give a better idea, the following table provides a sample of
data rows:

````
```{r table, results='asis', echo=FALSE} 
r = read.table("C:/aR_files/data.txt",sep=",", header=TRUE,as.is=TRUE)
r$X = NULL;
print(xtable(r), type='html') 
```
````

### Latex

```
In order to give a better idea, the following table provides a sample of
data rows:


Row1

Row2

Val1

Val1
```

I thought I may be missing a latex package, so I downloaded ctable.sty, but still I get the same output. Any ideas appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you show your actual code (a reproducible example)?

Comment: +1 @DavidRobinson, a small knitr file with a table produced by xtables, and perhaps what .md file is produced by that and the .tex file that is produced by that? (or the commands you used to generate the .md/.tex files so we can reproduce)?

Comment: @DavidRobinson ,  Thank you I updated my post. I  will add html output soon as well.

Comment: Without data.txt we can't reproduce this- can you do `dput(r)` to show what is in `r`?

Comment: This is a known issue. HTML tables in markdown are not converted to latex by `pandoc`. A workaround is to use the `ascii` package which can be used to produce table output in `pandoc` style, which renders fine both in html and latex. The alternative is to control table style using `options(xtable.type)` and setting it to `latex` or `html` depending on the type of output you are trying to produce.

Comment: @Ramnath you could post that as an answer ... except that I don't think he is converting HTML -> Latex, just md->HTML and md->LaTex separately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a very similar workflow to yours and your best bet is to abandon the often clunky `xtable` package and use the `pander` package to print your tables. You can wrap any object that you might want to display as a table in the generic `pander()` function. This is a wrapper for the `pandoc.table()` function which has several options. If you specify the option `style = "XXX"` you can achieve what you are asking about here. There are 4 different styles you can choose from; "multiline" (the default), "grid", "simple", or "rmarkdown". I frequently knit rmarkdown documents from within Rstudio and then convert them to Word documents using the pander package:

```
library(pander)
Pandoc.convert("C:/Users/BlahBlahBlah/Document.md", format="docx")
```

All of the 4 table styles get turned into table objects upon conversion to .docx format, but only one table style looks right in the .docx document and the .html file that results from the initial "knit". That style is "rmarkdown". You can implement this 2 ways. One would be:

````
```{r table, results='asis'}
pandoc.table(myTable, style = "rmarkdown")
```
````

I prefer to set the table style globally at the beginning of my document however, ensuring that all my tables have the same formatting and also allowing me to use the more succinct `pander(x)` instead of the more verbose `pandoc.table(x, style = "someStyle")`:

````
```{r table, results='asis'}
panderOptions("table.style", "rmarkdown")
pander(myTable)
```
````

There are some side effects of using the `rmarkdown` style however. Mainly, it does not support newline characters within cells, so buyer beware. I experimented with the different styles and eventually decided that I liked the default style of "multiline" because of it's flexibility with line breaks within cells, even though the .html files I generate look silly. This doesn't bother me though, as I really only use the .docx files that I convert from the .md files. I wrote a [blog post](http://r-norberg.blogspot.com/2013/06/generating-tables-using-pander-knitr.html) about making nice tables that you might find useful. It weighs the pros and cons of several methods including `xtable()` and several `pander()` scenarios.